# Multiple import with similar directory adress in Unity3D

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

am creating an android game which uses the Facebook SDK already and now I wanna add Google's AdMob Unity package to my project. Both of these packages have some same file addresses. So what will happen now if I import the Admob package too.

Will the Facebook files be overwritten or skipped ?

Comment: Files related to Google Play Service and may be Android Manifest gonna replaced. Do not do that, filter them out, otherwise unity will make you to commit suicide. Second thing double check for any android library (*.jar), any duplicate library should not exist in same of different folders

Comment: got it solved the other way! But thanx.